SharePoint Calculated Column to get the First letter after a dash
I am trying to get the first character after an underscore "_"
So I can create a view based on that first charter, for instance 12345_Name (Title field) and then my calculated field would show N.
I tried =LEFT and a FIND for the _, but not getting the result I want.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try this:
=MID([CODE], FIND("_", [Code]) + 1, 1)

where [Code] is the name of the column with the underscore.


Source: MID function

The calculated formula provided by jleture works well. If the reply is helpful, please remember to accept it as an answer.
